# How can I change the outputs from two different wires to the same state (on/off) using one input, regardless of the previous states of the two wires?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

So, I've set up two traps near my base, hooked up to pressure plates.Inside each trap, I have some sticky pistons with blocks attached, such that when extended (turned on) no power reaches the various parts of my traps when the plate is triggered,rendering it deactivated. I have one of these for each trap, and it's basically some buttons with  T-flip flops (to allow multiple buttons to have the same effect).

Is there any way to build a gate/device/contraption/thingy such that it changes both of the outputs to the same state(on/off) no matter what state they were in before? NOTE: I'm using the XBox 360 edition.

My "deactivation system" ( flip flop- turned off):

[image: picture of deactivation system]

The sticky piston it's attached to. Note that it is retracted:

[image: picture of sticky piston]

When the toggle is on, the piston blocks the redstone current, so the trap is inactive. I have a second trap with the same setup. Is there a way for me to make a master switch that toggles both pistons or flip-flops on or off (together) even if one is on and the other is off (i.e both traps can be switched on/off together)?

Comment: Could you provide us with a picture or diagram? I'm a bit confused by what you are asking.

Comment: alrighty. give me a few minutes to upload some pics

Comment: Cool, I've come up with a simple design, I'm just not sure if it matches your needs.

Comment: How do I....add pictures from my computer? pardon my incompetence...

Comment: There is a little button that looks like a picture in a frame, click that and upload it from your computer.

Comment: well, after spending 15 mins uploading pictures it says I don't have enough reputation :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you have something like this:

[image]

Teal is the two T Flip-flop, red is the mechanism modifying the state, and purple is the resulting output. In all the examples, the **right** T flip-flop *won't* be outputting a signal and the **left** T flip-flop *will* be outputting a redstone signal.

### **Wire ON/Torch OFF**

[image]
Rather simply, a switch can be put in place to force this wire ON and the torch OFF.

### Wire OFF/Torch ON

[image]
The pistons allow the T flip-flops to continue transmitting power to the output. When the switch is flipped off, the pistons retract, causing the line to disconnect and the wire to be in the OFF state, and the torch to be in the ON state.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see. Very Clever! I'll try out both designs and see which works best